# How to move rows up and down in a table on some button click in Angular2?

Tags: html-table, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Below is my code for a html-table, I need to add a function which on the
click of button moves rows up or down?

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Token</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let value of values">
                    <td>
                        {{value.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.key}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.token}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.color}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="editvalue(value);">edit</button> |

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Can you help me how can I do this? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It can easily do with updating data item indexes as follows.

**Html**

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead class="thead">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Token</th>
                    <th>Color</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let value of values; let index = index;">
                    <td>
                        {{value.name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.key}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.token}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{value.color}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="moveUp(value, index);">Move Up</button>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="moveDown(value, index);">Move Down</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

**Component.ts**

```
moveUp(value, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
      const tmp = this.values[index - 1];
      this.values[index - 1] = this.values[index];
      this.values[index] = tmp;
    }
  }

 moveDown(value, index) {
        if (index < this.values.length) {
          const tmp = this.values[index + 1];
          this.values[index + 1] = this.values[index];
          this.values[index] = tmp;
        }
      }
```